# Trying to end for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a loop that allows the user to enter as many elements to the array as they would like then sum up those elements. I need the loop to terminate when the user enters a negative number. How would I go about terminating this?

```
double sum = 0;
double group[] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {

    cout << "Please enter employee salary. Enter negative number to end." << endl;
    cout << "Employee " << i + 1 << ": $";
    cin >> group[i];
    if (i < 0) {
        break;
    }
    sum += group[i];
}
cout << "The total salary ouput for Ernest Inc is: $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << sum << endl;
```

Comment: You're sure about `if(i<0)`?

Comment: Your group[] array has a size of 1 and will never expand.

Comment: `if (group[i] < 0) break;` will do it.   Of course, there is also the problem that the loop will keep reading to `group[i]` while increasing `i`.   That will result in undefined behaviour eventually.   By whichever comes first of running past the end of `group`  (e.g. reading `group[10]` if `group` has ten elements or less) or by overflowing `i` (which has undefined behaviour for signed integral types like `int`).     Arrays or standard containers in C++ do not magically resize themselves on an attempt to access a non-existent element.

Comment: @Peter can you write that as an answer? Comments aren't meant for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the loop to terminate when the user enters a negative number.

For that a `while` loop would be better than `for`. You should also use `vector` which allows arbitrary number of items.

Something like this:

```
    vector<double> group;
    double salary;
    while (true)
    {
        
        cout << "Please enter employee salary. Enter negative number to end." << endl;
        cout << "Employee " << i + 1 << ": $";
        cin >> salary;
        if (salary<0)
        {
            break;
        }
        group.push_back(salary);
        sum += salary;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't even explained the fix and hid it with your change of loop.

Comment: yeah s/he should also use vector instead.

Comment: That will further hide the fix OP needed! Explain in a paragraph how testing `salaray<0` will work instead of `i<0`. That way OP can learn from that mistake